# Visual Studio 2010 Warning: Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I see quite a few posts on this error but none seem to relate to my situation.  I have a small solution containing 2 winforms apps and a data access DLL.  I am using VS2010 with SP1.

When I open the solution on my Vista Business 32 bit SP1 laptop it all works no problems.  However when I open the exact same solution on my Vista Ultimate 64 bit SP1 desktop I get the above error as soon as I open the solution and each time I attempt to build the solution.

There are no unusual tools, components, or libraries installed or used in the solution so it has me very confused.

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Thanks and kind regards.

Comment: Vista SP2 has been out for _over_ two years. The Vista Platform Update was released in late 2009. Both should be installed on your computer before attempting to figure out what's wrong with Visual Studio. It could quite easily be related.

Answer (score 4):

Are you linking to any native/COM libraries?

If so, you must change the solution's build target from `AnyCpu` to `x86`.

Not sure, but this might also happen if you've mixed CPU target types in fully managed solutions...

Comment: Thanks so much, your answer helped me fix same type of error I was getting in building a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just some while back when i started runnning the load test te following error dialog box appears "  unspecified error(Exception from HRresult : 0x800004005(E_FAIL)) ".

Resolution: Very simple just close the VS application and go the solution explorer window select the project and refresh two times. Now try the same it will work fine.

Regards,
VIVEK M

Answer (score 1):

run visual studio as administrator, i had same issue and when i run vs as administrator problem gone.